# Can this be done with blender? Abstract particle lights

Tags: particles

This tutorial from years ago shows an abstract light particle effect done in Blender Render. How can I re-create this with the updated/modern program using Cycles? Would love to do this with the actual particle system as shown in the tutorial. The smooth/wavy light trail is something I want to recreate, but I want to have it as a particle system as shown in this video so that the trail has some vorticity and physics. The only problem is this guide is outdated and I can't get it to work with modern Blender.

The halo rendering system he uses isn't in Blender anymore, but I would still like to get my particle trail to match this aurora light-trail style instead of just being made up of little noticeable particle shapes and I don't want to do fluid simulations. Would I convert the particle trail to a solid mesh or something and then apply shaders and modifiers? Or maybe I would find some way to implement point density textures? But I have no idea how I would start approaching something like that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhW79zJMBRc&

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, the particle trails option is no longer available. I've just tested that particles now have motion blur, depth, and vector data for the compositor. But I don't think that will help here. You can bake the particle path. I've tried this as animation and the result was that Blender 2.93 and 3.0 crash very often. Indeed it worked only 1 time :-/ This tutorial uses baked particles paths (https://youtu.be/RHvs1c1lz-I)